# Process records from database parallely in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a requirement to read a set to records from database, invoke an external api for each of these records and finally save the response. Now these records can be quite large. > 5million. So i am planning to read them batch by batch.

I know how to do this in java. Use multiple threads and a concurrent collection to store data. Run them all in infinite loops until there is no data to process.

How can i do this in node? This is what i can think of.

1) I create on promise for DB read and one for db write
2) Create say 5 promises for api call. When on of them returns with response, i save trigger the db write response and start a new api call (promise).
3) Or do i use a process.nextTick() kind of trigger in a infinite loop?

Am i thinking correct? or is it the java way of doing it? Also how can i run these node methods or promises (db reads, writes, api calls) etc infinitely until there are no records?

Comment: In this I would try with streaming db records to nodejs app. I dont know which db are you using, but here is example for PG https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-query-stream. You could then transform stream to parallel stream.

Comment: I can choose the database. I need to get the data to an external application, which can only be accessed by apis. So the idea is to have a separate application read from db, stream it to another node app, right? Cool idea, never thought about that. Always designed it like a single app with read and write together...

Comment: You can stream db data to your application. It doesnt need to be separate application ;) Maybe read firstly about Node.js streams https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Comment: Ok.. got it.Will check that..